# Xam.Media.Plugin Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm using excellent Xam.Plugin.Media nuget package in my Xamarin forms app to allow users to take photos. I have followed the example code from the Xam.Plugin.Media github page:

```
takePhoto.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
{
await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
{
    DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
    return;
}

var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
{
    Directory = "Sample",
    Name = "test.jpg"
});

if (file == null)
    return;

await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
{
    var stream = file.GetStream();
    file.Dispose();
    return stream;
}); 
};
```

However, this fails on android with the error message:

> Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (5312x2988, max=4096x4096)

Is there any way around this? Ideally using a PCL bitmap library

Comment: the beta version of the plugin allows you to specify size and compression factors for the image

Comment: @Jason I set the PhotoSize to Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Small and CompressionQuality to 92 and I'm getting the same error message. Any ideas?

Comment: you can use https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading as your image view. It has DonwsampleToSize attribute, which will downsample your image to match your image view, it will eliminate this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android uses bitmaps that resizes the image based on the display resolution and density. 
You will have to downsize it to the size you want. You can write your own bitmap factory to do it. 
Or you can use the [FFImageLoading](http://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) with downsampling. 
Or use the image transformations and actually resize the image altogether.

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"
            DownsampleToViewSize="true"
            Source = "http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg" />
```

References :

1. [Xamarin.Forms API](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API)
2. [Downsampling properties](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API#downsampling-properties)
3. [GetImageAsJpgAsync(int quality = 90, int desiredWidth = 0, int desiredHeight = 0)](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API#getimageasjpgasyncint-quality--90-int-desiredwidth--0-int-desiredheight--0)
4. [GetImageAsPngAsync(int desiredWidth = 0, int desiredHeight = 0)](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API#getimageaspngasyncint-desiredwidth--0-int-desiredheight--0)